# Update chart range to the end row

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to update the ranges in an existing chart with a macro. My data will always start on the same row but will continue to grow as a new data is added (e.g. $AK$15, $AK$16). I know this can be done by using dynamic charts but I've been asked to do it via VBA. My code is as follows:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview - Tier 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Activate
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Graph Data - Tier 1").Range("$AI$9:$AK$14")
```

I tried to modify my code as below but it doesn't work (I have a Runtime error 1004: Application-Definied or object-definnied error)

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview").Activate
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Worksheets("Graph Data").Range("$AI$9" & Rows.Count)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Activate
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Graph Data").Range("$AI$9::$AK$14 & LastRow")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: For start, change `"$AI$9::$AK$14 & LastRow"` with `"$AI$9:$AK$" & LastRow`. However you have some errors on your code. For example, you declared `LastRow` as long when you defined it later as a range of cells.

Answer (score 0):

This may helps:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Data")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")
        .ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Graph Data").Range("AI9:AK" & LastRow)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Error 1004. When I run this line 
       `.ChartObjects("Chart 7").SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Graph Data").Range("AI9:AK" & LastRow)` I'm having the `Run-time error '438' - object doesn't support this property or method`. Not sure how to modify this

Comment: I have now uploaded a screenshot in my original post. It's a combo chart. Cheers

Comment: Also i have make a small change in the code. please try again.

Comment: I tried your updated code. It does work, however it also selects all blank cells underneath my data. Is there any way to select all cells with data only?

Comment: Check LastRow value, because i can not see column names or sheet name from the pic you upload.

Comment: I checked the LastRow values but cannot figure out what to change. I have now uploaded another picture showing column names. The sheet name is 'Graph Data'. Cheers

Comment: The calculation of last row seems to be correct. i can not figure out something else.

Comment: I will play around this and let you know. Thanks anyway Error 1004